Proving the convergence in $L^1$

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Suppose
that $X_n$ has a binomial distribution $B(10, 0.2)$. Define $U_n =
 \min \{ X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \}$. Show that $U_n$ converges in $L^1$
and almost surely to $0$.

I have proven that $U_n$ converges almost surely to $0$. Here is my attempt:
$\forall\epsilon\in (0,1), \mathbb{P}(|U_n|>\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(U_n>\epsilon)+\mathbb{P}(U_n<-\epsilon)<(0,9)^n$
Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(|U_n|>\epsilon)<\infty\Rightarrow$ $U_n$ converges a.s to $0$. (Borel-Cantelli)
I'm stuck at proving $U_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

$U_n \to 0$ a.s and $0 \le U_n \le X_1$. Since $EX_1<\infty$, it follows by Dominated Convergence Theorem that $U_n \to 0$ in $L^{1}$.

Nice! Thank you

You don't need to show almost sure convergence and you can do it directly.
Just note that $P(\min(X_{1},...,X_{n})> x)=P(X_{1}> x)\cdots P(X_{n}>x)=(1-x)^{n}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$
Thus the cdf is given by $F(x)=\begin{cases}0\quad x<0\\
1-(1-x)^{n}\quad 0\leq x\leq 1\\
1\qquad x>1
\end{cases}$
And hence the pdf is given by $n(1-x)^{n-1}\quad,0<x<1$.
So $E(U_{n})=n\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)^{n-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0$ and hence $U_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}0$
(We can evaluate the integral by using Integration by Parts or the Beta Function)
